# Way to print for eval (literals) instead of for human-readable?

Tags: haxe

I see that `trace()` and `Sys.print()` both give me human-readable output. For example, if I print out the array

```
var a = ["", "1", "", "2", "3"];
```

I get printed:

```
[,1,,2,3]
```

Is there some kind of "eval print" function that will give me output instead like:

```
["", "1", "", "2", "3"]
```

That is, the literal that I could then use to copy/paste into code if I wanted to (and, incidentally, what could be eval'd to give me that exact array of strings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Json](https://api.haxe.org/haxe/Json.html) for that

```
trace(haxe.Json.stringify(a));
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but this is very useful, and also convenient!

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution might be to use [`haxe.macro.Printer.printExpr()`](https://api.haxe.org/haxe/macro/Printer.html#printExpr). [`ExprTools.toString()`](https://api.haxe.org/haxe/macro/ExprTools.html?#toString) is a convenience function that does this for you. Note that this requires passing the array literal to the macro function directly, instead of passing an identifier like `a` (whose value is not known at compile time).

```
import haxe.macro.Context;
import haxe.macro.Expr;

using haxe.macro.ExprTools;

class Main {
    static function main() {
        var string:String = printExpression(["", "1", "", "2", "3"]);
        trace(string); // source/Main.hx:9: ["", "1", "", "2", "3"]
    }

    static macro function printExpression(e:Expr):Expr {
        return macro $v{e.toString()};
    }
}
```

Other than that, you'd probably have to implement your own version of 
 [`Std.string()`](https://api.haxe.org/Std.html?#string) that prints strings with quotes.

Comment: Although this answer may be more technically correct, it's not as useful for me (not being able to just pass in the identifier), so I marked Andrew's answer with the green checkmark.